# Order vector in R: Letter with number sorts funny

Tags: r

Why can't I sort this vector 
`sort(c("r_1", "r_2", "r_10"))` as`r_1, r_2, r_10`?

The result is:

```
"r_1"  "r_10" "r_2"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `mixed_sort` from `gtools`.  According to `?mixed_sort`

> These functions sort or order character strings containing embedded numbers so that the numbers are numerically sorted rather than sorted by character value.

```
library(gtools)
mixedsort(v1)
#[1] "r_1"  "r_2"  "r_10"
```

---

The reason for the sort is that it is not a numeric `vector`.  So, sorting happen

#### data

```
v1 <- c("r_1", "r_2", "r_10")
```